# Python did not throw an indent error, but did not execute code

Tags: python, python-2.7

While teaching a friend python i came across a weird case involving issues with indentations.

Following is the piece of code which i was using

```
while 1:
    a = raw_input("input: ")
    if not a:
        break
    values = a.split()
    print values
```

So the issue was the friend used tab to indent the first 4 lines i.e

```
while 1:
    a = raw_input("Input: ")
    if not a:
        break
```

and then used spaces to indent the remaining code. i.e. following part

```
    values = a.split()
    print values
```

The piece of code did not throw the indentation error, which i guess is right because the tabs were defaulted to create 4 spaces.

Where it really got weird was that the unless the break condition was met, the part which used spaces was not getting executed.

i.e the output was as follows

*Input*

```
Input: 123 123 123
Input: abc abc abc
Input: pqr abc 123
```

*Output*

```
['pqr', 'abc', '123']
```

*Expected Output*

```
['123', '123', '123']
['abc', 'abc', 'abc']
['pqr', 'pqr', 'pqr']
```

Why could this be happening?
What am i missing about the battle of tabs and spaces in python interpreter

Comment: The second part *is* getting executed, but it's outside the loop so only gets executed *once*, for the final input.

Comment: @jonrsharpe Since it matches the indent levels i think its in the right indent levels. If i am wrong, could you explain it a bit more?

Comment: Well if you weren't wrong you'd see the expected output, surely? The output you're seeing tells you exactly how it's getting interpreted

Comment: AFAIK, Python interprets a tab not as four, but eight spaces, so technically, that code should be _after_ the `break`, i.e. unreachable. That's also how it behaves for me, e.g. when I replace the `break` with `pass`.

Comment: @tobias_k That is not true and is irrelevant anyway - there's an error is you have tabs and spaces in a single python source code file.

Comment: @Psytho, python2.7, used here, allow mixed intend. Python 3 will display an error, but it's not the case here.

Comment: @tobias_k You just tried what?

Comment: @Psytho I tried mixed indentation, but I just realized that I indented the first lines with space and the last with tab. If the first are tab and the last are spaces, then I get in fact an indentation error.

Comment: I correct myself: Python 2.x seems to [allow mixed indentation](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/lexical_analysis.html#indentation). I always get an error though.

Comment: Thanks @all for the information. Now I understand what is happening. Funny little mistakes make you learn more! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python 2 has exactly one interpretation of tabs: They are equivalent to eight spaces, always (your IDE may show them as something else, but Python and your IDE aren't on speaking terms). Knowing that, your final statements are clearly outside the loop body.

Python 3 doesn't have this problem; if you mix tabs and spaces, it will raise a `SyntaxError` (refusing the temptation to guess, per The Zen of Python [`import this`]). I'd suggest configuring your editor to make literal tabs display differently (e.g. in `vim`, `set listchars=tab:~>,trail:#`, `set list` shows tabs and trailing space as characters), and of course, configure it to automatically expand newly inserted tabs (e.g. `set expandtab`), not just interpret them as four spaces (in fact, having them interpreted as eight spaces would give you a more accurate interpretation of how Python 2 will see it).

Alternatively, [invoke the Python 2 interpreter with `-t` or `-tt`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#tabs-or-spaces) which makes mixed tabs and spaces warnings (`-t`) or errors (`-tt`), to make this sort of problem easier to stamp out.

Comment: "Knowing that, your final statements are clearly outside the loop body." Yes, but where are they, then? If the last lines are indented with 4 spaces, and the rest with tabs (i.e. 8 spaces) then those two lines should not be on any valid (previous) level of indentation and hence yield an error.

Comment: Now i understand whats going on with the code!
Also it was the friends IDE, who is complete beginner and doesnt know much about the ZEN code or the PEP8 stuff.
Thanks for the information!

Comment: @tobias_k: The OP stated that the first four lines were indented with a tab; that includes the `while`. I'm guessing the original code was in an indented block (not shown). If the `while` (that looks like it's not indented) and next three lines have a preceding tab, and the last two lines are preceded by four spaces (also not shown), then the `while` is really at 8 spaces worth of indent (for not shown tab), and the last two lines are at 4 (not shown) + 4 (shown) spaces, for a total indent of 8 spaces.